# How to copy data to the clipboard from the info panel?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

For example:
[image]

I am wanting to copy some data from the info panel, preferably `x, y, width and height` to my clipboard. Is this possible within Photoshop? The reason I ask is because I have hundreds of items that I need to grab coordinates from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem we can script this in a minute (10 to be exact, I'm a bit rusty). Put this script in a *.jsx*  file and run it using extend script toolkit:

```
#target photoshop

main();

function main() {
    var layers = app.activeDocument.layers;
    var file = File.saveDialog('save layer info', 'layerinfo:*.txt');
    file.open('w');
    handleOnelayer(layers, file, "");
    file.close();
}


function handleOnelayer(layers, file, pf){
    var numLayers = layers.length;
    for (var j = 0; j < numLayers; j++) {
       var currentLayer = layers[j];

       if (currentLayer.typename == 'ArtLayer'){
           var bounds = currentLayer.bounds;
           var name = currentLayer.name;
           var width = bounds[2] - bounds[0];
           var height = bounds[3] - bounds[1];

           file.write(
           pf + name+":\n" +
           pf +       "    X = " + bounds[0] + "\n"+
           pf +       "    Y = " + bounds[1] + "\n"+
           pf +       "    W = " + width + "\n"+
           pf +       "    H = " + height + "\n\n"
           ); 
        } else if (currentLayer.typename == 'LayerSet'){
            var name = currentLayer.name;
            file.write(
                pf +"--  " + name+"  --\n"
            ); 
            handleOnelayer(currentLayer.layers,
                           file, 
                           pf + "    ");
        }
    }
}
```

It will ask for a file name where to write the X, Y, W and H data. Example output:

```
--  Group 1  --
    Layer 2:
        X = 245 px
        Y = 103 px
        W = 786 px
        H = 366 px

Layer 1:
    X = 1360 px
    Y = 382 px
    W = 47 px
    H = 139 px

Background:
    X = 0 px
    Y = 0 px
    W = 1913 px
    H = 1200 px
```

Comment: I mean is this good enough or do you really need it on clipboard? Need XML?

Comment: Well, that was awesome. You just probably saved me several hours (and more) of tedious alt-tabbing :) -- Never knew scripting was that powerful within Photoshop.