# How can I get a Photoshop script (Javascript) to write a newline in a file instead of Control-M?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, javascript

I'm using JavaScript script in Photoshop (Ps 22.5.1 on macOS 11.6) to write out some information to a file.

When I represent a newline in my code with a \n, instead of getting a newline I get a ^M (control-M) in the file.  How can I get a normal newline in the output?

Here is an example script that demonstrates the problem.  I have this saved as test.jsx and am calling it in Photoshop as File->Scripts->Browse and then selecting the script.

```
#target photoshop

main();

function main() {
    var file = File("/some/path/test_info.txt");
    file.open('a');
    file.write("this is line #1\n");
    file.write("this is line #2\n");
    file.close();
}
```

The output is:

```
this is line #1^Mthis is line #2^M
```

The ^M characters are actually control-M, though if I do an "od -c" on the file I see they are \r (?):

```
$ od -c test_info.txt 
0000000    t   h   i   s       i   s       l   i   n   e       #   1  \r
0000020    t   h   i   s       i   s       l   i   n   e       #   2  \r
0000040
```

BTW, the script is loosely based on [this code snippet from StackExchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64028/how-to-copy-data-to-the-clipboard-from-the-info-panel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.writeln('str')` (*write line*) instead of `file.write('str')` (*write*).  Also you won't need the `\n` in your code after each line.

You can check the [PS Tools Guide](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/products/indesign/pdfs/JavaScriptToolsGuide_CS5.pdf) for more info on the File I/O functions.

Comment: Just tried that and unfortunately I see no change.  However, setting file.lineFeed = "Unix" before writing makes it work.  Bizarrely, setting lineFeed to "Macintosh" produces the control-Ms, while "Unix" doesn't.  Thanks for putting me on the right scent!

Comment: @raindog308 weird. I also usually set file encoding to UTF-8, maybe that's what was missing? `file.encoding = "UTF-8";`